# How do I convert a string of binary numbers to their signed decimal representation using C++?

Tags: c++, string, binary, twos-complement

I have a string:

```
1010
```

The unsigned representation of the string comes out be 10 after doing:

```
string immediateValue = "1010";
char immediateChars[5];
strcpy(immediateChars, immediateValue.c_str());

char * ptr;
long parsedInteger = strtol(immediateChars, &ptr, 2);
```

As I understand strtol can be used to only get unsigned representation. Is there a way to get the 2's complement value which would be -6?

Comment: `long tc = parsedInteger | (long(-1) << immediateValue.length());`

Comment: @ChristopherOicles `long(-1)` should be written as `-1L`

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc I wanted to make explicit that its is the same type as the target -- it would be easy for the OP to miss this if I just used a suffix (Granted, he runs into trouble with `long long` -- the function cast would fail using g++).

Comment: Also, just do `strtol(immediateValue.c_str(), &ptr, 2);`, no need for the `strcpy` step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your first character, if it is `0` then use `n` = `strtol` normally, if it is `1` then flip the bits, e.g. "1010" to "0101", then take `strtol` of the flipped string, the negative of that value minus one is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are binary strings and you have to convert them to denary.

Nuisance. The strings are likely too long to simply be packed in a long long, which makes life a lot easier (shove the bits in the long long, then call sprintf()). You'll havew to write your own binary division routine, divide by binary ten ("1010") and take the remainder. That's your last digit. Then repeat until the number goes to zero. As a last step, reverse the denary digits to match the most significant digit to the left convention.

It's quite a hunk of code but reasonable as learning exercise.

Comment: Alright thanks. It's part of a bigger project and I was trying to see if there was some sort of C/C++ trick to help me with it. But I guess you can't avoid the unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Code based on @tnt's answer which worked for me -

```
    bitset<32> b("11111111111111111111111111111111"); //step 1
    string flipped = b.flip().to_string();
    char *ptr;
    int num = std::strtol(flipped.c_str(), &ptr, 2); // step 2
    num *= (-1); // step 3
    num += -1; // step 4
```